# How to implement a Search inside a Nested Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement a keyword search for a field which is located inside Nested Array of Objects. How can I achieve it?

Data -

```
const groupList = [{
 "group_name": "General",
 "trainings": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "training_name": "Plural Sight",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "training_name": "Google Maps",
    }
 ]
}]
```

Code -

```
const [groupsData, setGroupsData] = useState([]);

const lowerContains = (str1, str2) => str1 && str2 && str1.toLowerCase().indexOf(str2.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

const handleSearch = searchKeyword => {
    if (searchKeyword && searchKeyword.trim()) {
      const groupFiltered = groupList.filter(item => item.group_name && lowerContains(item.group_name, searchKeyword));
      setGroupsData( groupFiltered );
      return;
    }
    setGroupsData({ [...groupList] });
};
```

Currently I am able to search with `group_name` but I want to also search with `training_name` inside `trainings`.

Comment: what is inside `lowerContains()` function?

Comment: @VMT Added the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the group object if the `searchKeyword` is contained within the group name OR one of the training name objects, you can use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). By using `.some()` on `trainings`, you can check if there is at least one object within the `trainings` array that contains a `training_name` value that matches your keyword search:

```js
const groupFiltered = groupList.filter(item => 
  (item.group_name && lowerContains(item.group_name, searchKeyword)) ||
  (item.trainings.some(training => lowerContains(training.training_name, searchKeyword)))
);
```

Note: In the example data you shared, `group_name` always contains a value, so you can remove the `item.group_name &&` check if that is always the case.

See working example below:

```js
const groupList = [{ "group_name": "General", "trainings": [{ "id": 1, "training_name": "Plural Sight", }, { "id": 2, "training_name": "Google Maps", } ] }];
const lowerContains = (x, y) => x.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase());

const searchKeyword = "Plural";
const groupFiltered = groupList.filter(item => 
  (item.group_name && lowerContains(item.group_name, searchKeyword)) ||
  (item.trainings.some(training => lowerContains(training.training_name, searchKeyword)))
);

console.log(groupFiltered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search inside the `trainings` if `group_name` is not matched using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) operation on the `trainings`.

Try like below.

```
  const handleSearch = (searchKeyword) => {
    if (searchKeyword && searchKeyword.trim()) {
      const groupFiltered = groupList.filter(
        (item) =>
          (item.group_name && lowerContains(item.group_name, searchKeyword)) ||
          item.trainings.some(({ training_name }) =>
            lowerContains(training_name, searchKeyword)
          )
      );
      setGroupsData(groupFiltered);
      return;
    }
    setGroupsData(groupList);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's "Array.some" method.

```
const containsTraining = (item, keyword) => {
  return item.some(
    (training) =>
      training.training_name && lowerContains(training.training_name, keyword)
  );
};
```

This will return true if item (one single group) contains at least one training that has the training name search keyword.