# Filter JSON object in nested array in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implemenet a search input filter inside drop down which contains nested dropdown list items.
My JSON data which I am getting from api as response given below

**API response**

```
glPlmAsmt.category = {
    "page_size": 100,
    "total": 5,
    "size": 5,
    "page_offset": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Program Governance",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca3d6c3bf060",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619902.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Risk & Issue Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca9ab6aed051",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1543489628.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Process & Tools",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca1fd776d743",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863427.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Planning",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Caeb46a6dce6",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620426.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Monitoring & Tracking",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Caeb46a6d1b2",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620426.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Compliance to Standards",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca0c8335afc6",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621467.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Engineering Maturity",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca3891dbcd9c",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535620156.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Requirements Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca53e3a3f610",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620405.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Technical Solution Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca6b44070713",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863770.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Quality Assurance",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Cac7a654f1c9",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620387.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "CI\/CD Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca7ba190bcca",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863878.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Team Management",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca009c852e4a",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619879.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Technical Expertise",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca6c3344d6cf",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565864050.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Design",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca414304c958",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620904.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Engagement",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Cafe3fcd7218",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620895.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Fulfillment",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca59511f47d7",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863978.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Domain Expertise",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca375bc31659",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620915.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Client Management",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca03453473e2",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619885.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Client Satisfaction",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Da414304c960",
                    "created_by": "PR-EmQR61tch032",
                    "created_time": 1535620904.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Stakeholder Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca7ff7f293a5",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621056.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Value Strategy",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca632e3b4005",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621083.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Contract Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca632e8a41a7",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621083.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Financials",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca49906fcb17",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619853.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Revenue",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca873f87fde3",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620651.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Labor Expenses",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca5ecf370d0f",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620664.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Other Expenses",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca1b195c5dfe",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620679.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is that I am trying to implement search on **name** property of **subcategories** such that if I enter keyword **tec** then it should show result object in which subcategories name contains keyword user entered, which  like this

```
        {
            "name": "Engineering Maturity",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca3891dbcd9c",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535620156.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Technical Solution Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca6b44070713",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863770.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Team Management",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca009c852e4a",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619879.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Technical Expertise",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca6c3344d6cf",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565864050.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Javascript Code for filteration**

```
    const groupList = glPlmAsmt.category;
    const lowerContains = (x, y) => x.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase());

    const searchKeyword = element;
    const groupFiltered = groupList.filter(item =>
      (item.name && lowerContains(item.name, searchKeyword)) ||
      (item.subcategories.some(subname => lowerContains(subname.name, searchKeyword)))
    );
    console.log(groupFiltered);
```

I referred this code from here, which is somewhat similar [How to implement a Search inside a Nested Array of Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72326895/how-to-implement-a-search-inside-a-nested-array-of-objects)

However it is not working properly for this JSON data

**point 2**

Even if search is get implemented then how to search other items as the array will be modified in first search item.

**I am stucked, kindly assist.**

**Thanks**

Comment: Are you assigning the paging object to `const groupList`? I believe you want to assign the items of the paging object `const groupList = glPlmAsmt.category.items`?

Comment: Discobarry: yes i am assigning object to const groupList and want to assign the items of the paging object

Answer (score 1):

```js
const category = {
    "page_size": 100,
    "total": 5,
    "size": 5,
    "page_offset": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Program Governance",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca3d6c3bf060",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619902.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Risk & Issue Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca9ab6aed051",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1543489628.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Process & Tools",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca1fd776d743",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863427.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Planning",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Caeb46a6dce6",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620426.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Monitoring & Tracking",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Caeb46a6d1b2",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620426.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Compliance to Standards",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca0c8335afc6",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621467.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Engineering Maturity",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca3891dbcd9c",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535620156.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Requirements Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca53e3a3f610",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620405.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Technical Solution Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca6b44070713",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863770.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Quality Assurance",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Cac7a654f1c9",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620387.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "CI\/CD Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca7ba190bcca",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863878.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Team Management",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca009c852e4a",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619879.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Technical Expertise",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca6c3344d6cf",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565864050.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Design",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca414304c958",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620904.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Engagement",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Cafe3fcd7218",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620895.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team Fulfillment",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca59511f47d7",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1565863978.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Domain Expertise",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca375bc31659",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620915.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Client Management",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca03453473e2",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619885.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Client Satisfaction",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Da414304c960",
                    "created_by": "PR-EmQR61tch032",
                    "created_time": 1535620904.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Stakeholder Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca7ff7f293a5",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621056.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Value Strategy",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca632e3b4005",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621083.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Contract Management",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca632e8a41a7",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535621083.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Financials",
            "status": "active",
            "id": "PL-Ca49906fcb17",
            "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
            "created_time": 1535619853.0,
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "name": "Revenue",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca873f87fde3",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620651.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Labor Expenses",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca5ecf370d0f",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620664.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Other Expenses",
                    "status": "active",
                    "id": "PL-Ca1b195c5dfe",
                    "created_by": "191ad6043e2e",
                    "created_time": 1535620679.0,
                    "subcategories": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const lowerContains = (x, y) => x.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase());

const searchKeyword = "tec";
const copyData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(category["items"])); // Point second 2
const groupFiltered =  copyData.filter(item => 
  (item.name && lowerContains(item.name, searchKeyword)) ||
  (item.subcategories.some(t => t.name && lowerContains(t.name, searchKeyword)))
);

console.log(groupFiltered);
```

I have normalize code & correct some syntax & for second time search it will filter original data so I have make copy of data before performing filter functionality

Answer (score 1):

You code is okay, only that since there are 2 filters involved, its logic becomes a bit complex. If the outer filter returns a `true`, the outer one does the same, therefore the entire `category` will be returned - no matter what condition you checked in the inner filter.

Therefore the only solution is to create another temporary array to hold the `filteredCategories` (those that match the search term), then loop over the categories using say a `forEach`, then inside it, filter the `subCategories` based on the search term. Since you only want categories and their subCategories (which match the search term), check if the `filteredSubCategories length is > 0`. If so, replace the `category.subCategories` array with the `filteredSubCategories` array and push this new category to the `filteredCategories` array. (Quite a mouthful)...

I would do something along these lines:

```js
const lowerContains = (x, y) =>
  x.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase());

let filteredCategoryItems = [];

glPlmAsmt.category.items.forEach((item) => {
  const filteredSubCategories = item.subcategories.filter(
    (subCategory) => lowerContains(subCategory.name, searchTerm)
  );

  if (filteredSubCategories.length < 1) return;

  const filteredItem = {
    ...item,
    subcategories: filteredSubCategories,
  };

  filteredCategoryItems.push(filteredItem);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there are 2 issues with your current code:

1. You are trying to use .filter on an object, not an array. Your object has a property called 'category' and in it, a property called 'items', which is your array.
2. Your filter conditions are not structured correctly, having both && and || in the same sequence, which results in a wrong truthy value in some case.

You should try using parentheses over your conditions to group the correct parts together:

```
const groupList = glPlmAsmt.category;
const lowerContains = (x, y) => x.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase());

const searchKeyword = 'tec';
const groupFiltered = groupList.items.filter(item =>
(item.name && (lowerContains(item.name, searchKeyword) || item.subcategories.some(subname => lowerContains(subname.name, searchKeyword)))));
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupFiltered));
```